# How to overlay a canvas dynamically onto an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, devexpress

I have an `img` tag and I need to draw on it with a transparent overlay.

I was thinking about a `canvas` mathing the image size and position, but because my context is dynamic I need to adjust there parameters with `javascript`.

I tried to work with `canvas.style.left`, `canvas.style.top` but they not seem to work as expected (`canvas.style.left` works only if I assign `0` to it).

Furthermore, when I assign the `width` and the `height` like this:

```
canvas.width = img.clientWidth
canvas.height = img.clientHeight
```

It seems not to get the right values.

I'm using `DevExpress` to dynamically load the `BinaryImage` from a `Model` fetched from a database, this is the portion of code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
    @if (Model.Image != null) {
        Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage(
                        settings => {
                            settings.Name = "mapImage";
                            settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
                        }).Bind((Model.Image).ToArray()).GetHtml();
        <canvas id="mapOverlay" ></canvas>
    }
</div>
```

Note that the `DevExpress` code results in the following `img` element:

```
<img class="dxeImage_Material" id="mapImage" src="/DXB.axd?DXCache=e86a5e5f-7d8b-4704-9330-ec7b9fa2ad38" alt="" style="width:100%;">
```

Is there any `DevExpress` component to use I may not be aware of that I could use?

**EDIT** 
Following this code:

```
    function DrawPoint(x, y, z) {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mapOverlay");
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    console.log("Setting canvas stuff");
    var img = document.getElementById('myMap');
    console.log("Image x: " + img.x)
    console.log("Image y: " + img.y)
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.style.left = img.x + "px";
    canvas.style.top = img.y + "px";

    clearCanvas();
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
    c.closePath();

}
```

The `console.logs` inside the function tells me that `img.x` and `img.y` are both `0`, but if I get their values from the console in my browser they have some value.

What can this be?

Comment: Would you be able to post a working example via the stack overflow code snippet tool?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... No I can't post a working example since I get the image and other stuff from a database, and everything is inside a MVC5 web application :(

Answer (score 1):

Note that the canvas width/height attributes are different from canvas width/height styles. Attributes effect drawing, while style effects rendering. See below:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


 var drawStuff = function(canvas, context) {
  context.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  context.stroke(); 
 }

 var imageMouseEnter = function(event) {
  var image   = event.target;
  var canvas  = document.getElementById("overlay");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.style.left = image.x + "px";
  canvas.style.top = image.y + "px";
  canvas.style.width = image.width + "px";
  canvas.style.height = image.height + "px";

  drawStuff(canvas, context);
 };

 var imageMouseExit = function(event) {

 };

 var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
 for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', imageMouseEnter);
  images[i].addEventListener('mouseout', imageMouseExit);
 }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="overlay" width="100" height="100" style="position:absolute"></canvas>

<div style="width:350px">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/145x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x65" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have not ignored you. I'm just drown in deadlines... I will let you know how it goes when I'll try it, but I sense this might be the solution, since I forgot to append the "px" to the canvas values!

Comment: My need is a different context, but I was able to adapt your suggestions to my needs. I managed to match the size of the canvas to the size of the image, but as for top and left I have some problems.
Moreover, I suggest you to use canvas.width and canvas.height, since the style attribute does not change the canvas resolution, resulting in a bad drawing (I found out experimenting). Sometimes I get img.x and img.y both equal to zero, but after a while they get != 0 values. Can I ask you why? I'm going to show what i mean editing my question and adding some code